# losing streak loop in hangman C#

Tags: c#

I'm trying to make a Hangman game in C#. It has a 5 tries limit, then the user will get a "you lose" message. If the user gets a letter wrong, it was supposed to get them a "wrong letter -- try again"

```cs
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string word;
        int correct = 0;
        int errors = 0;

        Console.WriteLine("Enter a word");
        word = Console.ReadLine();

        char[] letters = word.ToCharArray();
        char[] hanged = word.ToCharArray();

        char digits;

        for (int i = 0; i < word.Length; i++)
        {
            if (letters[i] == ' ')
            {
                hanged[i] = ' ';
            }
            else
            {
                hanged[i] = '_';
            }
        }
        Console.Clear();

        do
        {
            Console.Write(" ________\n" +
                                 "|        |\n" +
                                 "|        |\n" +
                                 "|\n" +
                                 "|\n" +
                                 "|\n" +
                                 "|\n" +
                                 "|\n" +
                                 "|\n\n");
            Console.SetCursorPosition(2, Console.CursorTop - 2);

            for (int i = 0; i < word.Length; i++)
            {
                Console.Write(hanged[i] + " ");
            }

            Console.WriteLine("\n\n\nEnter a letter");
            digits = Convert.ToChar(Console.Read());

            for (int i = 0; i < word.Length; i++)
            {
                if (digits == hanged[i])
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("\nletter already in there -- press enter");
                    Console.ReadKey();
                }
                else if (digits == letters[i])
                {
                    hanged[i] = digits;
                    correct++;
                }
                else if (digits != letters[i])
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("\nwrong letter -- try again");
                    errors++;
                    Console.ReadKey();
                }

                if (errors == 5)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("\nYou lose");
                    Console.ReadKey();
                    break;
                } else if (correct == word.Length)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("\nYou win");
                    Console.ReadKey();
                    break;
                }
            }

            Console.Clear();
        } while (correct < word.Length);

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

However, my program is stuck in a loop when counting the losses. The code thats messing it up is this section

```cs
else if (digits != letters[i])
{
    Console.WriteLine("\nwrong letter -- try again");
    errors++;
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

When I delete this section and run the code, in case of a wrong letter it just runs over it infinitely and the player will get infinite chances to try when they were supposed to have only 5 chances. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the 2nd loop `for (int i = 0; i < word.Length; i++)` that is responsible for finding a letter should not perform other logic in there. E.g., if the user types a letter matching the third position, then this will count 2 errors before counting one correct letter and also do extra console input and output.

I suggest using `Array.IndexOf` to get the index of a letter. This returns -1 if it is not found. Also, I found that the different kinds of `Console.ReadXY` can interfere with each other. E.g. calling `Console.Read()` and pressing a letter plus <kbd>Enter</kbd> makes the next `Console.ReadLine()` just return without waiting for user input.

My attempt (content of `static void Main(string[] args)`):

```cs
string word;
int correct = 0;
int errors = 0;

Console.WriteLine("Enter a word");
word = Console.ReadLine();

char[] letters = word.ToCharArray();
char[] hanged = word.ToCharArray();

char digits;

for (int i = 0; i < word.Length; i++) {
    if (letters[i] == ' ') {
        hanged[i] = ' ';
    } else {
        hanged[i] = '_';
    }
}
Console.Clear();

do {
    Console.Write(" ________\n" +
                            "|        |\n" +
                            "|        |\n" +
                            "|\n" +
                            "|\n" +
                            "|\n" +
                            "|\n" +
                            "|\n" +
                            "|\n\n");
    Console.SetCursorPosition(2, Console.CursorTop - 2);

    for (int i = 0; i < word.Length; i++) {
        Console.Write(hanged[i] + " ");
    }

    Console.Write("\n\n\nEnter a letter: ");
    ConsoleKeyInfo key = Console.ReadKey();
    digits = key.KeyChar;

    int hangedIndex = Array.IndexOf(hanged, digits);
    int lettersIndex = Array.IndexOf(letters, digits);
    if (hangedIndex >= 0) {
        Console.WriteLine("\nletter already in there -- press enter");
        Console.ReadLine();
    } else if (lettersIndex >= 0) {
        hanged[lettersIndex] = digits;
        correct++;
    } else {
        Console.Write("\nwrong letter -- try again (press enter) ");
        Console.ReadLine();
        errors++;
    }

    if (errors == 5) {
        Console.WriteLine("\nYou lose");
        break;
    } else if (correct == word.Length) {
        Console.WriteLine("\nYou win");
        break;
    }

    Console.Clear();
} while (correct < word.Length);

Console.ReadKey();
```